# What are the difference between knelt and kneeled?

Tags: differences

kneeled ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kneel)):

> to go down or rest on the knees or a knee.

knelt ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/knelt?s=t)):

> a simple past tense and past participle of kneel.

Comment: *kneeled* and *knelt* mean the same, they're just spelling variations of the past participle tense. E.g *spelled* and *spelt*; *learned* and *learnt*. Look at the first link, D.C says: knelt OR kneeled

Comment: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/kneeled-versus-knelt